# Spherical Triangle

Tags: triangles, area, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I know that the area for a spherical triangle is calculated as
Area $= r^2(a+b+c-\pi)=r^2E$ where $E= (a+b+c-\pi)$ is the spherical excess I was wondering why do you have to multiply by $r^2$ (the radius)?

Comment: If you stretch the sphere, then the surface area of the sphere increases by a factor of $r^2$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : That's if you stretch it from $1$ to $r^2$.  Starting at $1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy True, thanks for clarifying (except that the radius stretches from 1 to $r$, not $r^2$)

Comment: OK, we're both wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Areas of figures with the same shape are proportional to the squares of distances involved.  Thus the area enclosed by a circle must be some constant times $r^2$.  The area of a regular pentagon whose side has length $s$ must be some constant times $s^2$.  And so on.  The constant depends on the shape.